# problems with my external hard drive

Tags: external-hdd

Hi i am new to ubuntu and tried to use my external hard drive, it works fine to access my files in the different dirs but in one of the dirs where i have all my mp3 files it finds no files at all, in windows it finds the mp3 files. What could cause this?

Comment: What is the directory's name? How the files are named?

Answer (score 1):

Is the directory synchronized via Offline Files?  If so, it isn't really a normal directory with files in it underneath the surface if it's the sync'ed copy and not the original (for example, if you have a laptop with a domain account and My Documents redirected to the server, but made available offline).

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you mean, but all the directorys on the external hard drive is just ordinary directorys made in windows, with files copied to them from some old hard drives i never use,whats strange is that i can access all other directorys but this directory when i open from ubuntu is totaly empty, and in windows it opens with all my files in it.

Comment: Some things to try: from the command line, try `ls -la /path/to/folder` - do you get anything showing up?  Also, if you have a file "myfavoritesong.mp3" that should be in that folder, try `find / -iname myfavoritesong.mp3` (this will probably take a few minutes to check your hard drive) and see if you get any results.